# Setting max-width for columns in antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to set a max-width for a column but it is not accepting the maxWidth property in antd.But it accepts width property. I have dynamic columns which will be of different lengths, so I wanna set a max-width property to column and then wrap the sentence after that. I need some help in fixing this, thanks.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-easley-jgobz8?file=/index.js:0-1137

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table, Divider, Tag } from "antd";
import Column from "antd/lib/table/Column";

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
    tags: ["nice", "developer"]
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park",
    tags: ["loser"]
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park",
    tags: ["cool", "teacher"]
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table dataSource={data}>
    <Column title="Name" render={(data) => data?.name} />
    <Column title="age" render={(data) => data?.age} />
    <Column
      maxWidth="50px"
      title="addressaddressaddressaddressaddress addressaddressaddress"
      render={(data) => data?.address}
    />
    <Column title="tags" render={(data) => data?.tags} />
    <Column title="Name" render={(data) => data?.name} />
    <Column title="Name" render={(data) => data?.name} />
  </Table>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, you can try to this way:

**index.css**

```
.custom-width {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

**index.js**

```
<Column
      className="custom-width"
      // maxWidth="50px"
      title="addressaddressaddressaddressaddress addressaddressaddress"
      render={(data) => data?.address}
    />
```

Comment: Thank you, since we are using styled components, is it possible to do like https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-easley-jgobz8?file=/index.js:598-641.  It is not accepting like this.